# Warning: Missing argument 1 for WP_Widget::__construct()

Tags: php, wordpress, widget

I am not really that familiar with PHP. I'm working on a WordPress platform website and have 'child theme configurator' plugin installed. When I go to 'analyze' my child theme it is coming up with the following errors. They all seem to be related to code on the same line in class-wp-widget-factory.php  line 71 which calls something

```
$this->widgets[ $widget ] = new $widget();
```

and is defined in class-wp-widget.php on line 162

```
public function __construct( $id_base, $name, $widget_options = array(), $control_options = array() ) {
```

It looks like there is/are undefined variable: name in class-wp-widget.php on line 164

```
$this->name            = $name;
```

Here are the errors that are coming up ( sorry for the length, but they might be redundant? )

Warning:  Missing argument 1 for WP_Widget::__construct(), called in /home/jpalenhouseblog/public_html/wp-includes/class-wp-widget-factory.php on line 71 and defined in /home/jpalenhouseblog/public_html/wp-includes/class-wp-widget.php on line 162

Warning:  Missing argument 2 for WP_Widget::__construct(), called in /home/jpalenhouseblog/public_html/wp-includes/class-wp-widget-factory.php on line 71 and defined in /home/jpalenhouseblog/public_html/wp-includes/class-wp-widget.php on line 162

Notice:  Undefined variable: name in /home/jpalenhouseblog/public_html/wp-includes/class-wp-widget.php on line 164

Warning:  Missing argument 1 for WP_Widget::__construct(), called in /home/jpalenhouseblog/public_html/wp-includes/class-wp-widget-factory.php on line 71 and defined in /home/jpalenhouseblog/public_html/wp-includes/class-wp-widget.php on line 162

Warning:  Missing argument 2 for WP_Widget::__construct(), called in /home/jpalenhouseblog/public_html/wp-includes/class-wp-widget-factory.php on line 71 and defined in /home/jpalenhouseblog/public_html/wp-includes/class-wp-widget.php on line 162

Notice:  Undefined variable: name in /home/jpalenhouseblog/public_html/wp-includes/class-wp-widget.php on line 164

Warning:  Missing argument 1 for WP_Widget::__construct(), called in /home/jpalenhouseblog/public_html/wp-includes/class-wp-widget-factory.php on line 71 and defined in /home/jpalenhouseblog/public_html/wp-includes/class-wp-widget.php on line 162

Warning:  Missing argument 2 for WP_Widget::__construct(), called in /home/jpalenhouseblog/public_html/wp-includes/class-wp-widget-factory.php on line 71 and defined in /home/jpalenhouseblog/public_html/wp-includes/class-wp-widget.php on line 162

Notice:  Undefined variable: name in /home/jpalenhouseblog/public_html/wp-includes/class-wp-widget.php on line 164

Warning:  Missing argument 1 for WP_Widget::__construct(), called in /home/jpalenhouseblog/public_html/wp-includes/class-wp-widget-factory.php on line 71 and defined in /home/jpalenhouseblog/public_html/wp-includes/class-wp-widget.php on line 162

Warning:  Missing argument 2 for WP_Widget::__construct(), called in /home/jpalenhouseblog/public_html/wp-includes/class-wp-widget-factory.php on line 71 and defined in /home/jpalenhouseblog/public_html/wp-includes/class-wp-widget.php on line 162

Notice:  Undefined variable: name in /home/jpalenhouseblog/public_html/wp-includes/class-wp-widget.php on line 164

Any assistance would be great. I know there are a lot of extremely knowledgeable coders here.

I've tried turning off several third party plugins that may be related to widgets such as WP Instagram Widget and then running the analyzer again but the same errors come up.

Thanks.

Dennis

Comment: If you're not familiar with PHP, how would you be able to understand an answer? You'll have to provide proper constructor arguments... however, I can't tell, which ones that are, this should be mentioned in the documentation of the widget or Wordpress...

Comment: @LarsStegelitz please reread my original post... "I am not THAT familiar with PHP..." , perhaps I should have worded it differently. Thanks for the comment.

Comment: Ok, my bad... apologies. I have re-read your post as suggested, here are my thoughts. First: there are no errors, only warnings and notices. Second: They are all originated in WP itself. Third: Looks pretty much like an inconsistency in WP - the Widget factory does not regard the Widget constructor parameters as defined in the base class. I would recommend to file this as bug report with the WP developers team...

Comment: Hi @LarsStegelitz. Thanks so much for the expert input. And you're right, they are warnings and not fatal errors. But being a bit obsessive/compulsive about my work, ha ha, I want everything to be as clean as possible. With your advice in mind, I think I will post this in the wordpress.org forums because it is likely a common wordpress glitch and perhaps an easy fix. Even though, currently these warnings don't affect the way this particular site works. Thanks again. Best   Dennis